# How to solve the sql server 2008 restore error 3203

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to restore the database in SQL Server 2008. The backup file is  SQL Server 2008 from another PC **. When i want to restore show me the error**

TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

```
------------------------------

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Read on "D:\New Folder (2)\mihirreliance.bak" failed: 38(Reached the end of the file.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3203)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3203&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Why this problem aries .How to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

The Cause of the Problem is that the Drive in which your Source Data base files are located is not present in your server where you want to restore  the database.

Please use the  SQLCMD Promt and use the Manula RESTORE command  with REPLACE and MOVE option .But before using the Restore command get the logical file name of your source database

syntax:

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE [TestServer28Sep2010] 
FROM DISK = 'C:\BackUp\TestServer28Sep2010.bak'
WITH  REPLACE ,
MOVE 'SourceLogicalFileName_Data'     TO   'D:\JapanTestServerDB\TestServer28Sep2010.mdf',
MOVE 'SourceLogicalFileName_log' TO   'D:\JapanTestServerDB\Server28Sep2010.ldf'
```