# Read error 3203 trying to restore SQL Server 2008 R2 over SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Environment:

- Server A: W2008 R2 server with SQL Server 2008 R2, compatibility level=100
- Server B: W2012 server with SQL Server 2012, compatibility level=100

Both servers are virtualized, n different places/networks/domains.

Backup to a disk file from Server A is verified and restorable on Server A.

The problem arises when that backup file is copied to Server B to be restored:

- Trying to restore via SQL Server Management Studio: no database appears on the datagrid of backup sets after specify the file on disk to be restored.
- Trying to restore via T/SQL command

  ```
  RESTORE DATABASE [mydb] 
  FROM DISK = 'C:\bkTest\mydb.bak' 
  WITH REPLACE
  ```

  errors are (in spanish)

  ```
  > Mens. 3203, Nivel 16, Estado 2, Línea 1    
  > Error de lectura en "C:\bkTest\mydb.bak": 38(Se ha alcanzado el final del archivo.) (ENG)=Read error, End of file reached
  ```

  I've verified with 'NET HELPMSG 38' that error 38 is EOF encountered

  ```
  > Mens. 3241, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1  
  > La familia de medios del dispositivo 'C:\bkTest\mydb.bak' no está formada correctamente. SQL Server no puede procesarla.  
  > Mens. 3013, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1  
  > Fin anómalo de RESTORE DATABASE*.
  ```

When I execute:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY 
FROM DISK='C:\bkTest\mydb.bak'
```

the grid of results contains one row with a lot of columns with info of the backup, ending with 'CompressedBackupSize' and 'Containment'. This shows that file is accesible. But I also get 3203 error ...

I've tried to copy from Server A to Server B not only by wire but also by pen drive with identical frustrating results

Additionally: I've verified instances via @@version : 2008R2 for Server A and 2012 for server B

Also tried 'WITH FORMAT' option for BACKUP command, without success.

Not tried yet copy of `.mdf` and `.ldf` files form A to B because A is in production and I prefer look for a solution before.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011782/how-to-solve-the-sql-server-2008-restore-error-3203 and this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/05/08/sql-server-backup-failure-error-3203-severity-16-state-1/

Comment: First, backup/restore in SQL Server works without problems, without requiring special arguments. The error is rather clear - the file is corrupt. No command line arguments are going to fix that. How did you copy the file? You didn't use any method that assumes the file is text ? Check the documentation of the backup/restore commands and *VERIFY* that the file is OK. To do that run `RESTORE` with [VERIFYONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188902.aspx) on the source server right after taking a backup. You should also use the `CHECKSUM` option on BACKUP

Comment: Thanks msanz, I already reviewed these links before.

Comment: (1/3) OMG! Panagiotis. You are right!. File is corrupted!. 
To verify that I've generated a new backup in A with checksum. 
I've verified that restore can be done in server A. 
I've copied to server B. Same error. 
But then I copied back the received file in B to server A and surprise! 
there is the same error and backup of this file can't be done now in server A.

Comment: (2/3) I can't figure out why this happens. 
I've copied via GUI-copy-paste between Terminal Server sessions from Server A to my Workstation 
and also via GUI-copy-paste from Workstation to virtual server B (under VMWAREplayer). 
Also tried previously with pen drive (after copy between TS sessions) 
with the same error so I supose I can discard VMware's copy manouver as guilty.

Comment: (3/3) I'll try to change the copy mechanism (via net mapping and commands I supose)
Thanks a lot Panagiotis, send your coment as answer and I'll mark as solution.

Comment: UPDATE
I've found the issue. 
I access Server A this way:
Open Terminal server session with remote DMZ-Server1.
From DMZ-Server1 I open another Terminal Server Session with Server A
I've detected that if I copy-paste the backup file from Server A to DMZ-Server1 the file grows by 3 Kb. and is not restorable
I think this growth is because DMZ-Server1 is Windows 2003 and Server B is 2008R2.
The problem is solved via mapping a network drive in server A pointing to a shared resource in DMZ-Server1, the copy didn't grows copying to mapped drive.

Thanks again